# Second TableView is not showing on the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have two tableviews in a menu controller. first tableview populates a dynamic menu list from db and second tableview should only display the strings I tell it. So right now I only need 2 cells, Settings and Login. The first table view works fine. But, the second is not displaying the items. code bellow represent the second tableview

ViewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.slidingViewController setAnchorRightRevealAmount:280.0f];
    self.slidingViewController.underLeftWidthLayout = ECFullWidth;
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2f alpha:1.0f];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2f alpha:1.0f];
    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.15f alpha:0.2f];
    self.extraTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2f alpha:1.0f];
    self.extraTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.15f alpha:0.2f];
}
```

Main table

```
-(void)setMenuItems:(NSArray *)menuItems
{
    if(_menuItems != menuItems)
    {
        _menuItems = menuItems;
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)sectionIndex
{
     return self.menuItems.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MenuItemCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    Department *dept = [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.text = dept.name;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2f alpha:1.0f];

    UIView *myBackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    myBackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = myBackView;
    return cell;
}
```

Second table

```
-(void)setExtraMenuItems:(NSArray *)extraMenuItems
{
    if(_extraMenuItems != extraMenuItems)
    {
        _extraMenuItems = extraMenuItems;
    }
    [self.extraTableView reloadData];
}    

- (NSInteger)extraTableView:(UITableView *)extraTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)sectionIndex
{
    return self.extraMenuItems.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)extraTableView:(UITableView *)extraTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Formal";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [extraTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [_extraMenuItemFiller addObject:@"Settings"];
    [_extraMenuItemFiller addObject:@"Logout"];

    NSString *cellValue = [_extraMenuItemFiller objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2f alpha:1.0f];

    UIView *myBackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    myBackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = myBackView;

    return cell;
}
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: What is your logic for calling the `extraTableView:...` methods?  (Those aren't names that the table view will look for automatically.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't rename the tableView delegate and datasource methods: just test the tableView parameter that is passed to them, to determine which tableView they relate to.  For example:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)sectionIndex
{
    if (tableView == self.extraTableView) {
        return self.extraMenuItems.count;
    } else {
        return self.menuItems.count;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.extraTableView) {
        NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Formal";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [extraTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        [_extraMenuItemFiller addObject:@"Settings"];
        [_extraMenuItemFiller addObject:@"Logout"];

        NSString *cellValue = [_extraMenuItemFiller objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2f alpha:1.0f];

        UIView *myBackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
        myBackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = myBackView;

        return cell;
    } else {
        NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MenuItemCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }

        Department *dept = [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.textLabel.text = dept.name;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2f alpha:1.0f];

        UIView *myBackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
        myBackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = myBackView;
        return cell;
    }
}
```

And likewise for all the other tableView delegate and datasource methods.  You also need to make sure that the delegate and datasource are set for both table views.  You can do either do this in your storyboard, or in code eg. in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.extraTableView.delegate = self;
self.extraTableView.datasource = self;
```

**EDIT**

You don't need both extraMenuItems and extraMenuItemFiller.  I would use just extraMenuItems.  Load it with the two values in viewDidLoad as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.slidingViewController setAnchorRightRevealAmount:280.0f];
    self.slidingViewController.underLeftWidthLayout = ECFullWidth;
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2f alpha:1.0f];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2f alpha:1.0f];
    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.15f alpha:0.2f];
    self.extraTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2f alpha:1.0f];
    self.extraTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.15f alpha:0.2f];
    self.extraMenuItems = @[@"Login",@"Settings"];
    self.extraTableView.delegate = self;
    self.extraTableView.datasource = self;
}
```

and amend the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to use extraMenuItems rather than extraMenuItemFiller:

```
    NSString *cellValue = [self.extraMenuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```